# Boto3 Instance Not Allowing SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I have created an instance using the Boto 22 interface, my connection arguments including key_id and access_key, and a new security group authorized with the following.

`security_group.authorize_ingress(IpProtocol="tcp",CidrIp="0.0.0.0/0",FromPort=22,ToPort=22)`

I create the instance with

`instance = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-5b41123e', KeyName='test_pair57', InstanceType="t2.micro", MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)`

I set the program to wait in a while loop until it finds the instance state is running. However, I still can't SSH into the public IP address it then prints out. The connection always times out. I have tried specifying the port, but that does not change it.

Do I need to pass my new keypair's fingerprint somewhere or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Lot of information missing. Did you use your private key when ssh-ing? What linux distro? Post the command you used.

Comment: Have you tried launching an instance through the AWS Management Console with the same settings, to see whether it works? If it works, you can compare the difference to your non-working instance. If it doesn't work, then it isn't related to boto, it's related to your settings. What is that AMI -- is it yours, or one from AWS? Was the instance launched in a Public Subnet? Can you connect to other instances in the same VPC & Subnet, or elsewhere? Any more information you can provide will assist us in being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My security settings were incorrect. Checking them in the AWS online interface allowed me to verify the settings and showed me the issue.

I needed to add my created security settings to the instance like so:

`instance = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=image.id, KeyName='test_pair' + str(rand), InstanceType="t2.micro", MinCount=1, MaxCount=1, SecurityGroupIds=[security_group.id])`